# Passing a function (with variable number of arguments!) as an argument

Tags: c++, arguments, function-pointers, argument-passing

I have a bisectionMethod function, which accepts a function as one of it's arguments. For the bisectionMethod's intents and purposes, the function argument it accepts has only one argument which is being optimized. But, I would like to pass any type of function (with any number of arguments) to the bisectionMethod function. I'm using a pointer function as an argument in the bisectionMethod function, but it requires that I specify exactly how many arguments go into that pointer function. What's the best workaround for this?

For example, I am trying to do something like this:

```
double bisectionMethod(double xMinimum, double xMaximum, double maxError, double (*rootFunc)(double))
{
    ...
    return ret;
}

double foo1(double x1, double y1){return x1 * y1;}
double foo2(double x2, double y2, double z2){return x2 * y2 * z2;}

int main(){

// I want to first be able to set y1 in foo1.
// Then I want to solve for x1
bisectionMethod(5, 250, 0.1, foo1(x1));

// I want to also be able to use bisectionMethod with foo2
// I want to first be able to set x1, and y1 in foo2.
// Then I want to solve for z1
bisectionMethod(5, 250, 0.1, foo1(z1));

return 0;

}
```

I hope the example makes sense. I know it's a bit strange. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just use a deduced type parameter and `std::bind`.

Comment: How about a C++11 lambda?

Comment: `I would like to pass any type of function (with any number of arguments) to the bisectionMethod function` — how would you call it in there?

Comment: can you please tell me do you want a function with variable no of argument or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;

double bisectionMethod(double xMinimum, double xMaximum, double maxError, function<double (double)>)
{
   ...   
   return ret;
}

double foo1(double x1, double y1){return x1 * y1;}
double foo2(double x2, double y2, double z2){return x2 * y2 * z2;}

int main(){

// I want to first be able to set y1 in foo1.
// Then I want to solve for x1
bisectionMethod(5, 250, 0.1, std::bind(foo1, _1, 1.0));

// I want to also be able to use bisectionMethod with foo2
// I want to first be able to set x1, and y1 in foo2.
// Then I want to solve for z1
bisectionMethod(5, 250, 0.1, std::bind(foo2, _1, 1.0, 2.0));

return 0;

}
```

This works for C++ 11. Use boost::bind for C++ 98.

Answer (score 0):

The boost version:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

double bisectionMethod(double xMinimum, double xMaximum, double maxError, boost::function<double(double)>)
{
    ...
    return 0;
}

double foo1(double x1, double y1){return x1 * y1;}
double foo2(double x2, double y2, double z2){return x2 * y2 * z2;}

int main(){

  // I want to first be able to set y1 in foo1.
  // Then I want to solve for x1
  bisectionMethod(5, 250, 0.1, boost::bind(foo1, _1, y1));

  // I want to also be able to use bisectionMethod with foo2
  // I want to first be able to set x1, and y1 in foo2.
  // Then I want to solve for z1
  bisectionMethod(5, 250, 0.1, boost::bind(foo2, x1, y1, _1));

  return 0;

}
```